# Why is the head bone missing from my Rigify rig after generating it?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I have been using Rigify to create a character rig, and I encountered an issue where the head bone is missing from the rig after generating it. I have tried to solve this problem through research and troubleshooting, but I haven't found a satisfactory solution for my exact model.[image]

[image]

Comment: Are all bone layers visible?

Comment: @joshsanfelici I'm not sure, I'm not that used to using Rigify. I'm just trying to rig a simple robot but am unable to do so correctly. Thanks for pitching in to help by the way!